# Generating file/folder structure based on combination of options, but with many options

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations

I'm writing a script that will generate all possible combinations of a list of options, with each option having different possible values. The options in question are either different library or built-in methods for testing and benchmarking their performance. Here's an example of the options and values:

```py
{
    "compiler": (
            "None",
            "Cython",
            "Numba_jit",
            "Numba_aot",
            "Nuitka_standalone",
            "Nuitka_onefile",
            "Pyston",
            "Pyjion",
            "ShedSkin",
        ),
        "packager": ("None", "PyInstaller", "PyOxidizer", "Nuitka"),
        "code_location": ("Local", "External"),
        "aggregators": (
            "Loop",
            "Map",
            "Filter",
            "Functools.Reduce",
            "Numpy_apply_over_axis",
            "Numpy_apply_over_axes",
            "Numpy_vectorize",
            "Numpy_frompyfunc + numpy.vectorize",
            "Numpy_piecewise",
            "Pandas_all",
            "Pandas_apply",
            "Pandas_agg",
            "Pandas_applymap",
            "Dask_delayed",
            "PyArrow_all",
            "PyArrow_array_filter",
            "PyArrow_filter",
        ),
        "data_storage": (
            "List",
            "Tuple",
            "Set",
            "Numpy_ndarray",
            "Numpy_ndarray_typed",
            "Pandas_series",
            "Pandas_series_typed",
            "Pandas_dataframe",
            "Pandas_dataframe_typed",
            "Dask_array",
            "Dask_dataframe",
            "Dask_bag",
            "PyArrow_array",
            "PyArrow_table",
        ),
        "internal_caching": deepcopy(caching_options),
        "external_caching": deepcopy(caching_options),
        "lambda": ("false", "true"),
        "partial": ("false", "true"),
        "data_comprehension": (
            "None",
            "List",
            "Tuple",
            "Set",
            "Generator_expression",
            "Generator_function",
        ),
}
```

I already have the method of generating all possible combinations and filtering out ones that I do not want (IE: can not have a combination where packager == "Nuitka" and compiler == "Cython")

I take these combinations and create a folder structure based on the option names and values like so:

```
compiler-None/
    packager-None/
        .... # nested all the way down
            program.py
    packager-PyInstaller/
        .... # nested all the way down
            program.py
    packager-PyOxidizer/
        .... # nested all the way down
            program.py
compiler-Cython/
    ...
```

The script creates the `program.py` files at the lowest nesting level of the directories, and contains a dictionary of the options that file will use.

The issue is that with roughly 10 options with each ranging from 2 to 15 values, even after the filtering I'm ending up with more than 137,760 combinations. That means that I generate 10 levels of directories before getting to the individual `program.py` files.

Is there a smarter way to create these file combinations that doesn't involve this level of nesting, but ends up cleaner than just having 137,760 files within one directory?

An extra note:

The reason each `program.py` file is generated and nested as described is that each file will have drastically different implementations than the others. Some implementations will utilize different compilers, comprehensions, etc. which would make it impossible for me to simply pass in a list of arguments and go from there. Each file would have an implementation that is too different from the others for me to combine them down into fewer files, at least in a way that I'm aware of.

The idea is that I would have a `main.py` file that would import the different `program.py` files, run their implemented function as a benchmark, and move on to the next function implementation.

Comment: Are you really going to run 137760 files (all with a compiler and other stuff to execute)?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't go 2-3 levels deep, then stop? The levels seem to follow the keys in your initial structure at the top, so the depth limit can be easily set by that.

Comment: 1. The app imports a single module, runs it with some parameters some number of times in a loop, and measures the execution time of each loop. Afterwards the module is unloaded and it'll move on to the next one

2. That was just an example - the nesting goes ALL the way down for the key-value pairs. With 10 options that 10 levels of depth, where one folder path will look like `compiler-opt/packager-opt/code_location-opt/aggregator-opt/data_storage-opt/internal_caching-opt/external_caching-opt/lambda-opt/partial-opt/data_comprehension-opt/program.py`